# Select distinct first character based on the string column

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, match, partial

In SQLite I have a table of contacts with one of the columns being `last_name`. How can I get unique set of first characters of all last names in the table? Something like `['a', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'w']`. It would help if query would be case insensitive. I'm using SQLite on Android. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT lower(substr(last_name,1,1)) AS last_initial FROM my_table;
```